# How to export .wav files within your jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, export, wav, executable-jar

In my java project I have wav files I want to play. I have the resources saved in a source folder.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ptsfb.jpg

In my code I refer to the wav files as such:

```
String path = "res/filename.wav";
```

Inside eclipse the files get played but when I export as runnable jar file the sounds doesn't get played at all.

Do I have to change something to the path I export it or is my path string that I use in my code wrong?

Comment: put your media file in raw folder and run it with code : MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.filename);
      mp.start();

Comment: @Revenge, this isn't asking about an Android app. The question specifically mentions "executable JAR."

Comment: @misoloo, show more of the code that you're using to load the `.wav` file. It's important to load resources the correct way when packaged as a JAR.

Comment: You should try retrieving your file through : `YourClass.class.getResource("res/filename.wav")`

Comment: I've found the problem. I was initializing the AudioInputStream in a way that didn't support exported jar files. After some research I found a working way to do it.